# Добавить json к ответу сервера

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-core

Есть список объектов (некоторые данные), которые достаются из БД. Я хочу, чтобы при обращении к сайту клиенту отдавалась страница, а вместе с ней и эти данные в формате json, для будущего взаимодействия с ними на странице при помощи js. Прочитал, что можно добавлять его к телу ответа сервера, но метод Response.Write() требует массив байтов, а  информации про то, как привести json к байтам  я так и не нашёл. Каким образом можно отдавать клиенту страницу с json?

```
    public IActionResult CheckFormulas(int categoryId)
    {
        // Данные, которые нужно передать в json 
        IEnumerable<Formula> formulas = _formServ.GetFormulasByCategoryId(categoryId);                      
        return View("CheckFormulas");
    }
```

Comment: Я прочитал ответы, но право непонятно, почему никто не предложил создать два экшена - один возвращающий разметку и другой возвращающий чистый json через `return this.Json(formulas);`. Вообще-то именно это является на текущий момент стандартом де   факто в индустрии, так что можно было идти на поводу формулировки задачи но хотя бы упомянуть о хороших практиках.

Comment: @AK вы предлагаете после получения и прогрузки страницы через ajax получать json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контроллере:

```
return View("CheckFormulas", formulas);
```

В представлении:

```html
@model IEnumerable<Formula>
<script>
   var data = @Json.Serialize(Model);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return View("CheckFormulas", formulas);
```

В представлении:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Formula>>" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var data = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;

</script>
```

Comment: У меня Script не находит в пространстве имён System.Web, в .net core его нет,  и объясните, пожалуйста, для чего первая строчка, так как VS тоже на неё ругается

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH Это заголовок представления для WebForms движка, для Razor должно быть по-другому.

Comment: Следуя вашему примеру, покопался и добрался до решения